# Public cardano-wallet service list

Tags: wallet, cardano-node

While I am checking cardano-wallet-js, I noticed requirement.

```
Before start using the library you will need a cardano-wallet server running.
```

Is there any public cardano-wallet server which I can use to initialize walletServer?

Answer (score 0):

No, as the `cardano-wallet` service holds information about your keys, accounts and so on.

But you can use [cardano-wallet](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet) with [Blockfrost.io in light mode](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-wallet/blob/master/docs/user-guide/common-use-cases/how-to-start-wallet-server.md) with the need to sync the entire chain which takes few days.